# Red Plant Growing in a Brick

Tags: identification

This Is growing in a brick in my backyard. 
Im Not Sure What It Is. Does someone Have 
An Idea? Is Shaped Like A Small Chinese Tree.

[image]

Comment: HA, that's amazing! HOW? I am assuming it's growing in a crack in the brick?

Comment: Do you have maidenhair fern in your area?  What zone do you live?

Comment: Please give us more information. Do you have other photos?